# How to stream STT file to IBM Watson (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I am using [IBM Watson Unity SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk)

There are some examples in the web on how to send file to IBM Watson.

But no exact examples how to stream a long file split to parts. So what I want to do:
**I have a log audio file (about 1-3min) and want to sent it to Watson to recognize speech.**

IBM Watson accepts only <5mb files, but my file is larger, so I need to split it  and send as parts.

Here is my code:

```
private void OnAudioLoaded (AudioClip clip)
{
    Debug.Log ("Audio was loaded and starting to stream...");
    _chunksCount = 0;

    float[] clipData = new float[(int)(clip.length * CHUNK_SIZE)];
    clip.GetData (clipData, 1);

    try {
        _speechToText.StartListening (OnRecognize);

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling (clip.length / SECONDS_TO_SPLIT); i++) {
            Debug.Log ("Iteration of recognition #" + i);
            _chunksCount++;

            // creating array of floats from clip array
            float[] chunkData = new float[SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * (int)CHUNK_SIZE];
            Array.Copy (clipData, i * SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * (int)CHUNK_SIZE, chunkData, 0, clipData.Length - i * SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * CHUNK_SIZE < SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * CHUNK_SIZE ? (int)(clipData.Length - i * SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * CHUNK_SIZE) : SECONDS_TO_SPLIT * (int)CHUNK_SIZE);

            // creating audioclip from floats array
            AudioClip chunk = AudioClip.Create ("ch", clip.frequency * SECONDS_TO_SPLIT, clip.channels, clip.frequency, false);
            chunk.SetData (chunkData, 0);
            AudioData audioData = new AudioData (chunk, chunk.samples);

            // sending recognition request
            _speechToText.OnListen (audioData);
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryException e) {
        DialogBoxes.CallErrorBox ("Audio Recognition Error", e.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is:

On line `_speechToText.StartListening (OnRecognize);` I assign a Callback function OnRecognize, that should be called when something is recognized, but it is never called.

This file i am testing on has been recognized, on online website and it is definitely ok.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to introduce OnError to read the actual error.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev not working either

Comment: The question is about the error message you get

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thats the problem that i don't get any error, so I don't know what should i fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the figure was that the data chunks where too small for Watson to recognize, so my solution to this specific problem was to send longer audio chunks, a few seconds long, about half a minute, and the recognition was working properly.

The longer audio file I was sending the better result I received, but still I had to be under 5mb.

This solution is very old, but it can help someone running into the same problem.